# If $(X_{i-1},X_i)\sim\mathcal L(X_{i-1})\otimes\mathcal N_Σ$, how do we need to choose the covariance $Σ$ to maximize the expected distance?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, normal-distribution

Let $\Sigma\in\mathbb R^{2\times2}$ be positive, $q$ denote the density of the 2-dimenional normal distribution with mean $0$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$ and and $$Q(x,B):=\int_B\lambda^{\otimes 2}({\rm d}x)q(y-x)\;\;\;\text{for }(x,B)\in\mathbb R^2\times\mathcal B(\mathbb R)^{\otimes2}.$$

Let $n\in\mathbb N$ and $(X_0,\ldots,X_n)$ denote an $\mathbb R^2$-valued process on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ such that $X_0\sim\delta_{x_0}$ for some $x_0\in\mathbb R^2$ and $$(X_{i-1},X_i)\sim\mathcal L(X_{i-1})\otimes Q$$ for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

> How do we need to choose $\Sigma$ if our goal is to maximize $$\min_{1\le i<j\le n}\operatorname E\left[\left\|X_i-X_j\right\|\right]?\tag1$$

Note that $$(X_0,\ldots,X_n)\sim\mathcal L(X_0)\otimes\kappa^{\otimes n}\tag2.$$ From this, we see that $$\operatorname E\left[\left\|X_0-X_1\right\|\right]=\int Q(x_0,{\rm d}x_1)\left\|x_0-x_1\right\|,$$ $$\operatorname E\left[\left\|X_0-X_2\right\|\right]=\int Q(x_0,{\rm d}x_1)\int Q(x_1,{\rm d}x_2)\left\|x_0-x_2\right\|,$$ $$\operatorname E\left[\left\|X_1-X_2\right\|\right]=\int Q(x_0,{\rm d}x_1)\int Q(x_1,{\rm d}x_2)\left\|x_1-x_2\right\|,$$ and so on ...

Comment: Do you mean $Q\mathbb{1}_B(x)=\int_B q(x-y)\,\lambda^2(dy)$?

Comment: Yes, $(Qf)(x)=\int\lambda^{\otimes2}({\rm d}y)q(x,y)f(y)$ for any Borel measurable $f:\mathbb R^2\to[0,\infty)$.

Comment: You may want to edit de definition of the operator $Q$ in your posting (you missed the set $B$)

Comment: $Qf(x)=f*p_{\Simga}(x)$ looks like a linear transformation of the kernel of Brownian motion in $\mathbb{R}^2$. As in a previous problem of your, you may need to fix the variances of the component and focus on the size of the covariance.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the missing $B$. Yes, I think we may need to fix $\Sigma_{11}$ and $\Sigma_{22}$ and optimize with respect to $\Sigma_{12}=\Sigma_{21}$.